# NodeJS & RabbitMQ - Error: Channel closed by server: 404

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, rabbitmq

I keep getting the error provided in the screenshot and I have logged everywhere in my code but I can't seem to find from where does this error get thrown,

[image]

- I will provide in the next lines the utility functions I use for connection and message exchange

```
    export async function createChannelAndQueue(): Promise<{ channel: amqp.Channel; queue: Queue }> {
        try {
            const mySingletonInstance = MySingleton.getInstance();
    
            const connection = await amqp.connect(brokerURL);
            let channel = await connection.createChannel();
            const queue = await channel.assertQueue('', { durable: false });
    
            mySingletonInstance.channel = channel;
            mySingletonInstance.queue = queue;
    
            channel.on('close', () => {
                console.log('Channel has been closed by the server');
                // Re-open the channel
                connection.createChannel().then((newChannel) => {
                    channel = newChannel;
                    mySingletonInstance.channel = channel;
                    console.log('Channel has been re-opened');
                });
            });
    
            return { channel, queue };
        } catch (error) {
            throw error;
        }
    }
```

```
    export async function sendMessage(
        channel: amqp.Channel,
        queuename: string,
        queue: Queue,
        message: any
    ): Promise<string> {
        const correlationId = uuidv4();
        try {
            const queue = await channel.assertQueue('', { durable: false });
    
            const result = await channel.sendToQueue(queuename, Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(message)), {
                replyTo: queue.queue,
                correlationId,
            });
            return correlationId;
        } catch (error) {
            throw error;
        }
    }
```